# In React, why would one be using %PUBLIC_URL% instead of relative urls?

Tags: reactjs

I'm tinkering with React.

In the [index.html template generated by create-react-app](https://github.com/react-cosmos/create-react-app-example/blob/master/public/index.html), the favicon.ico is referenced through the use of %PUBLIC_URL%.

```
<link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
```

This comment is right after, explaining that %PUBLIC_URL% is better than relative url.

```
  <!--Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
  work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
  Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.-->
```

I am not sure I understand what a non-root public URL is. I reckon is deploying your app on something like www.mydomain.com/subfolder instead of directlyon www.mydomain.com.
I'm not sure either why this  tag should be concerned with client-side routing.

I thought that PUBLIC_URL was there to allow developers to not worry about the link tag href value that could be different between development environment and production environment.

Since the content of the public folder is copied in the build folder, I think this issue could be juste as much solved by using a relative url. In both configuration (www.mydomain.com/subfolder/index.html  www.mydomain.com/index.html) the favicon would be found right next to the index.html file.

What am I missing?